When using macOS's iPhone Mirroring, is there a way to simulate "touch screen"?
I tried using iPhone Mirroring on the MacBook Air, to play Pokemon Go. I tried to touch the Poke ball, and throw it at a Pokemon, but it was very difficult to do that using the trackpad, because I have to click, move, and let go of the click. The action of "touch, move, and let go" is very difficult to be emulated by the trackpad (touchpad) on the MacBook if I have to click it to be considered a "touch".
Is there a way to make it work? Since there is no touch screen Mac, so maybe trackpad is the only way, or one good way, which can make it possible.
P.S. something like, if Shift-click, then even when you let go of the click (when you finish the click), the system still thinks you are still touching the screen. Then when your finger really leaves the touchpad, then it's considered not touching the screen on the iPhone.
